# Move controls automatically when Dragover on table layout panel in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I want to drag button on table layout panel that consist 4 row and 4 button each inside, when dragging over the panel I want the other button automatically move up or down depend on location the current button being drag over.

**Example :** if I drag new button to button2 , automatically button 2,3,4 move down empty the button2 place. I have tried out `mouseUp`, `mouseDown`, `MouseMove` events of control, but that is not what I am looking for.

Can I do this? If you can give me an idea it will be great.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: @soundslikeodd , mouseup, mousedown,mousemove are testing but never reach the idea i talk about :(.

Comment: Again, can you provide sample code that illustrates the problem you are having?